# Timer counting down until 10pm every day in vanilla JS

Tags: javascript, timer

I am making a data visualisation for a bar that closes at 10pm local time every day. Therefore, I would like to display a timer that counts down to closing time every day and I am not sure how to set the exact hour. Right now it is counting down one hour from the time the page is loaded, so I need help making it dynamic.

```
const timeSpan = document.getElementById("timer");
const mins = 60;
const now = new Date().getTime();
const deadline = mins * 60 * 1000 + now;

setInterval(() => {
  let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  let distance = deadline - currentTime;
  let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 3600)) / (1000 * 3600));
  let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  timeSpan.innerHTML =
    "Time until closing: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}, 50);
```

```
<span id="timer"></span
```

Comment: "counts down to 10pm" doesn't make any sense

Comment: @DanStarns a timer that ends at 10pm every day. And when it hits 10pm it restarts to 10pm the next day, Does that make more sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a `new Date` instance and set time using `setHour(hour, min, sec, ms)` method like I did.

```js
const timeSpan = document.getElementById("timer");
const mins = 60;
const now = Date.now();
let date = new Date();
// Set deadline hours, minutes, seconds, milliseconds
date.setHours(22, 0, 0, 0);
let deadline = date.getTime();

setInterval(() => {
  let currentTime = new Date().getTime();
  let distance = deadline - currentTime;
  let hours = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 3600)) / (1000 * 3600));
  let minutes = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60));
  let seconds = Math.floor((distance % (1000 * 60)) / 1000);

  timeSpan.innerHTML = "Time until closing: " + hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + seconds;
}, 50);
```

```html
<span id="timer"></span>
```